# How to pass variables from a static function of class1 to another class2?

Tags: java, android

I have intended to pass total weight from the function to another class. I plan to use getIntent(). However, a static function does not allow it. If that is the case, how should i pass it? Below is the static function of class1. I have been getting error at the "this" part.

```
public class Shopping{
public static double getShipping(double total_weight) {
    String weight = Double.toString(total_weight);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this ,shopping1.class);
    intent.putExtra(total_weights, weight);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    double shipping_fee = 0;
   return shipping_fee;
  }
  }
```

This is the class 2 function.

```
public class shopping1 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String weight = intent.getStringExtra(Shopping.total_weights);
    System.out.println(weight);
    new connect5(this,   
  this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).execute(weight);
}
}
```

Comment: STATIC functions can be called directly using class name

Comment: can you show me how to call?

Comment: make it void function and call your intent @CheongCharlene

Comment: Whats class name for getShipping() method

Comment: it has to be static and it cant be made void, cause other places are accessing this function as well

Comment: the class name is shopping

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers the current instance of an object, you cannot use it in a static method.

As a static method doesn't need an intance to be executed you should pass the object as parameter.

```
public static double getShipping(Object this, double total_weight)
```

You will need to change `Object` to the class you are using ( Activity, Fragment, Context...)

Once done you can call your static method like this

```
double weight = Shopping.getShipping(this, totalWeight);
```

Example

```
public static double getShipping(Context c, double total_weight) {
    String weight = Double.toString(total_weight);
    Intent intent = new Intent(c ,shopping1.class);
    intent.putExtra(total_weights, weight);
    c.startActivity(intent);
    double shipping_fee = 0;
    return shipping_fee;
}
```

Comment: besides "this", what else can i used?

Comment: Cause the total weight value is get from another class that pass the data to it. totalweight += weights * quantity; shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(totalweight);. Therefore after adding context to getShipping function, i should change my code to shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(Context c, totalweight)?

Comment: Cause when i put shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(Context c, totalweight), i have been getting null pointer exception error

Comment: Look it simple, if you wat to start an activity then you must pass a `Context`to your function. You cannot pass `null` check where you call your method...

Comment: Cause i dont understand why passing it like this shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(Context c, totalweight), will get null pointer. As i already put data inside the totalweight, it should have read it. Or is it the Context c

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you with your whole desgin. We are now to far away from your original question. SO is not a code factory...  I identified your issue with `this` I gave you a solutions. So please accept this answer if you agree that it solves your original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `Context` to your static method. From there you can share your data in multiple ways.

1) if your Activity is not started yet then you can use `startActivity()` and Intent extras.

2) If your activity is already started, you can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

```
LocalbroadcastManager.getInstance(context).setBroadcast(intent);
```